# Add animation to items being loaded intp webgrid MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, animation, onload, webgrid

I'm currently adding items to a webgrid and would like them to "transition in" on a timer. When and how do I execute this animation (with JQuery) as items begin loading in?

I load the partial view called "_PartResults" using the following .get ajax call:

```
 $.get("@Url.Action("_PartResults")", {
                        parameter1: parameterVariable,
                        parameter2: parameter2Variable....
                    }, function (data) {
                       // alert(data);
                        $('#divPartResults').replaceWith(data);
                        $('#divPartResults').find('tr').fadeIn();
                    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ for the API of `$.get` which indicates there is a `Success` callback.

You're already leveraging that callback with the function:

```
function (data) {
    // alert(data);
    $('#divPartResults').replaceWith(data);
}
```

So just change this to include your image transition/animation. If you were to change the code to use the full `Ajax` call, you could do something like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("_PartResults")",
    data: {
        parameter1: parameterVariable,
        parameter2: parameter2Variable....
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#divPartResults').fadeOut();
        $('#someLoadingImage').fadeIn();
    },
    success:  function (data) {
        // alert(data);
        $('#divPartResults').replaceWith(data);
        $('#someLoadingImage').fadeOut();
        $('#divPartResults').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I was not able to get any handle on fading in/out the data. The goal is to have control over the animation of each row within the webgrid, but it appears that the MVC html helpers load the entire chunk of data to fill the control at once.

Comment: I added a little edit to my question to help illustrate what I'm trying to achieve with the row-animations.

Comment: The data will always come in a single block so you cannot animate the data row by row (as far as I know), however once it's loaded you could add a row one at a time with an animation which may solve your problem

Comment: Yes, this is along what I am thinking. Could you provide me with an example of how to achieve this? This is my "stuck" point. So basically the whole chunk of webgrid data will be loaded in, and the rows are animated in one by one as if appearing for the first time (hidden until this occurs). Thank you for revisiting my question  :)